# Select all records that match criteria plus next record that does not match criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a table that has columns like this:

```
ID, Description, PC, Account, Amount
```

I'm going to be looking for a 009 value in the "PC" column, and each datum has a sequentially-numbered unique ID in the "ID" column.  Every datum with a 009 "PC" value will have at least one item following it that doesn't have "009" as a PC value.

Is there any way I can write a query that's real and similar to the fake code below?  Is something like this actually possible?

```
SELECT  
table.ID AS ID,  
table.Description AS Description,  
table.PC AS PC
WHERE ((table.PC = 009) OR (whatever, as long as table.ID-1's "PC" value = 009))
```

Comment: sample data and expected output will be great, and easy to understand

Comment: The question is not well formed and make no sense as far as it is formulated as: `Select all records that match criteria plus next record that does not match criteria`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id`s are really sequential, you can put the logic in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Description, t.PC AS PC
FROM table as t
WHERE t.PC = 009 OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM table as t2
              WHERE t2.id = t.id - 1 AND t2.PC = 009
             )
ORDER BY t.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
table.ID AS ID,  
table.Description AS Description,  
table.PC AS PC
FROM table
WHERE ((table.PC = '009') OR 
table.ID - 1 = 
  (
  SELECT table.ID
  FROM table
  WHERE table.PC = '009'
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    t.ID AS ID,  
    t.Description AS Description,  
    t.PC AS PC
FROM tbl t
WHERE 
   (t.PC = 009) OR 
    (t.id - 1 = (SELECT t2.ID FROM tbl t2 where t.PC = 009))
```